# php compare multidimensional array values in single dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two different array. One is single dimensional array like below.

```
Array
( 
   [0] => products_01.jpg
   [1] => products_02.jpg 
)
```

And Second array is multi dimensional array like below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [imgurl] => http://example.com/upload/products_01.jpg
            [name] => products_01.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [imgurl] => http://example.com/upload/products_02.jpg
            [name] => products_02.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [imgurl] => http://example.com/upload/products_03.jpg
            [name] => products_03.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [imgurl] => http://example.com/upload/products_04.jpg
            [name] => products_04.jpg
        )

)
```

Now i want to compare both array and if we get same value for key "name" then delete that array. **Without using foreach or for**. Do any one have idea that php provide any inbuilt array function or not ?

**I want Output Like Below**

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [imgurl] => http://example.com/upload/products_03.jpg
            [name] => products_03.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [imgurl] => http://example.com/upload/products_04.jpg
            [name] => products_04.jpg
        )

)
```

Comment: without using foreach? well there's a lot of alternative way to do that like array_map for example

Comment: @NewbeeDev Can you give me example Please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the single dimensional array is called $arrayA and the multi-dimensional array is called $arrayB, you could do the following:

```
$arrayB = array_filter($arrayB, function($arrayBItem) use ($arrayA) {
    return ! in_array($arrayBItem['name'], $arrayA); 
});
```

If you don't want to override the multi-dimensional array, $arrayB, assign the array_filter call to a different variable instead e.g. $arrayC.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!